# Set routes in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, regex, laravel-5.1

I'm new in laravel, I wants to make separate folder for admin & front end. I've made folder like this

```
app/http/Controllers/Catalog/Common/home.php 
app/http/Controllers/Admiin/Common/home.php
```

I wants to place common controllers in common folder like header, footer etc. In any another folder will be another related files like eg: category

```
app/http/Controllers/Catalog/Category/list.php 
app/http/Controllers/Catalog/Category/product.php 
app/http/Controllers/Admiin/Category/list.php 
app/http/Controllers/Admiin/Category/categoryForm.php
```

But I'm stuck to make it working with routes, Should I use the same logic in Laravel or is there a better way to do it? Please suggest me how can I do it?

Here are the first four lines of my home controller

```
namespace LocalProject\Http\Controllers\Catalog\Common;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use LocalProject\Http\Requests;
use LocalProject\Http\Controllers\Controller;
```

I'd really appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to have 2 websites running on the 1 laraval install? Surely it would make more sense to just use 2 separate installs? If you are just trying to create an admin area then why cant this just be protected using session data etc?

Comment: Nops.. I am not going to create 2 websites with single installation, just make two folder catalog for fronend code & admin for administrator code for single website.

Comment: If you are only using folders to make things more organised then it should work fine. Have you tried it out yet?

Comment: Tried lot of combination of routes .. for now using
Route::get('/{controller}/{method}', function($controller, $method) {
    $name = "\App\Http\Controllers\\" . $controller . 'Controller';
    $class = new $name();
    return $class->{$method}();
});

Answer (score 1):

Routes work based off of namespaces, class names, and functions.

`\Namespace\Classname@functionName`

Folder structure shouldn't matter.

Edit for some more question specific answers:

You probably want to use something like this:

```
Route::get("home/index", [ "as" => "home.index", "uses" => "\LocalProject\Http\Controllers\Catalog\Common\HomeController" => "HomeController@index" ]);
```

You may also want to look into `Route::group` to help keep your namespaces more organized.

Comment: I've namespace like this namespace LocalProject\Http\Controllers\Catalog\Common;  Can you please let me know who routes will be ruled ?

Comment: That's mosty likely not the namespace of your file, the default namespace for Laravel is 'App', it's the first line in your files.

Comment: yeah, I've gave you my first line of contoller home, I've created this home controller by using php artisan make:controlle command.

Comment: Can you post the first 4 lines of each file in your question?

Comment: Added mate, please see the question now.

Comment: I gave you an example for the home controller under the assumption that the class name is HomeController.php

Comment: No Luck Mate, Getting error with your solution (FatalErrorException in routes.php line 14:
syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ']')

Comment: Well you should be able to debug that, at a glance it just looks like I forgot to include quotes around the uses, so it should be "uses" =>